# IE10 Favicon Issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10, favicon

I've googled this issue, read all the threads, done what they have said and still I am having a problem trying to display a simple favicon.ico in IE10!

The file size is 16x16 (I have also tried 32x32) and it works perfectly in Chrome, FireFox and Safari so I know I have implemented the code right.

This is what I have done so far:

1) Placed the favicon.ico in the root folder

2) added these lines of code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.barnhillmarketing.co.uk/favicon.ico" type="image/x-    icon"> 
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

3) Tried both absolute and relative URLs.

4) Cleared my internet cache / history and rebooted still with no joy.

5) Made the icon again in a favicon generator still to no avail.

If anyone has a fix for this then that would be fantastic as I am at my whits end with this :-/ If you go to http://www.barnhillmarketing.co.uk/favicon.ico you will see the icon shows up so I have no idea what is going on here :-(

Thanks in advance,

Keith

Comment: Have you tried removing the second `<link..`, When I've added favicons in the past I've only ever used the `<link rel="shortcut icon"...` tag and they work fine in IE10

Comment: I had a similar issue recently, you don't actually need any references to the `favicon` in the `head` section actually. As long as you have the `.ico` file in the root directory then it will be picked up. Some converters produce broken `.ico` files, you could try this one - http://convertico.com/ as it worked for me.

Comment: @NickR I've just tried the convertico.com and it has now worked for me! I removed the referenced in the head section as well so thank you v.much for your answer :-)

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it sorted, IE can be a `bit` of a pain some times :)

Comment: Hello @NickR, I am hosting my application in Tomcat, for the applications in the webapps folder, this solution is working fine but it is not working when I have application out side of webapps folder, Can you throw me some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a few days ago. If you change the path of the favicon using versions for example its clears all caching issues.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=1" type="image/x-icon" />
```