# Favicon doesn't show on IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

I've created a 32*32 favicon.ico and placed it in my root.
it works well on Chrome, but not on IE10. I have cleared cache (went to Safety > Delete browsing history > marked Temp internet files, cookies and website data)

None of these combinations work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Content
    </body>
</html>
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: Is the `favicon.ico` in the root folder?  Does it work if you remove the `<link>` tag altogether?  Browsers will auto-load favicons if they are in the root folder.  (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use)

Comment: yes its in the root, and it doesn't work neither without the `<link>` (except on Chrome), I don't see in my server log a request for a favicon from IE either with or without the tag, only from Chrome.

Comment: It could be because of the size.  Does it work if you use a 16x16 icon (and `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />`)?

Comment: Does the browser actually make a request for the file? Does it get the URL correct? (check your server logs for the requests, and for any 404s) Is it actually an ICO file? (ie you haven't just created a PNG and named it .ico?) Does it get served with the correct mime type? What happens if you try to open that URL directly in the browser? (do you see the image?)

Comment: See his comment, he says he checked the server log.

Comment: @Barmar - ah, that wasn't there when I started typing my comment.

Comment: Could it be a caching issue? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316682/ie10-favicon-issue)

Comment: It works fine when tested on another website, seems like this is because my website has password protection currently for testing purposes, however it does work well on chrome and FF, and I do type the correct password on IE as well (otherwise I won't see the page it all). Could it stem from the password protection? doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @rockyraw: Is the `favicon.ico` also password protected?  Maybe IE doesn't update the favicon after you log in.

Comment: yes the whole root folder is with htaccess password protection. tried clearing the cache without closing the browser so it would keep the password and yet look again for the .ico, but it doesn't look for it