# How to get my logo to be the icon image in internet browser tabs?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a favicon that I would like to display on the IE tab when on my site.

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE10 and above but not for IE9 and below.

Currently I am using the following in the `<head>` tag:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#$.siteConfig('themeAssetPath')#/css/ie/ie.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#$.siteConfig('themeAssetPath')#/css/ie/ie_overrides.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="#$.siteConfig('assetPath')#/images/favicon.png">
    <![endif]-->
```

Hoping it will target all IE but it isn't working.

Is their another approach so the Favicon appears on the IE9 and below tabs?

Thank You

**UPDATE**

As you can see below, I have converted the favicon. However, it still does not display the logo.

I have tried the following way to see if the icon will appear:

```
<!--[if LTE IE10]>
        <link rel="icon" href="#$.siteConfig('assetPath')#/images/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
    <![endif]-->
```

And this approach:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="icon" type="/image/ico"  href="/favicon.ico" >
```

Yet neither show the results I am looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [favicon not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: You need to use an `ico` file. IE10 and below [do not support png favicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support).

Comment: What is the `#$.siteConfig('themeAssetPath')#` in this? You will have to convert your png to an icon.

Comment: Ahh okay, Thank you. I was not aware of the ico file. So if I still call it in where I have it to only focus on ie10 and below, it should work right?

Comment: @pcnate: I do not understand what you are asking

Comment: Use an online system for auto generating all nessecary icon files: [Fun Website that does just that](http://realfavicongenerator.net/)

Comment: Thank you, I already have converted the file but it still displays the ie logo. I will shortly paste what I did

Comment: Your image needs to be favicon.ico instead of .png format and try adding  type="image/x-icon".

Comment: @KaushalPatel I have recently updated what I did and yes I did add that type you mentioned

Comment: check file path?  maybe try, "./favicon.ico"

Comment: @john_h I have tried that approach and yields the same results

Comment: how about: "~/favicon.ico"

Comment: Could it be the way I have it currently: <link rel="icon" href="#$.siteConfig('assetPath')#/~/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon" />?

Comment: Can you change it to a direct local path to test it? I don't understand the file path: "#$.siteConfig('assetPath')#/~/favicon1.ico"

Comment: @john_h I did and it works now. Its weird, it works for another png image. Thanks for you help

Comment: @john_h how do i target IE 10. I realize it shows the conditional statement which it shouldnt

Comment: This could be a caching issue: take a look at this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316682/ie10-favicon-issue  update with the relevant html so we can take a look

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot